# How to create an array of unique keys with the largest element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, split

I am trying to find out largest number from groups and assign them into an array of unique groups. I tried using map and lodash uniq but didnt help

> Example

Lets say the main array consists of a typeid and a number seperated by colon (:)
I want to identify the largest number in from each typeid and they create an array out of it.

From the below example i am trying to generate an output like below

```
["abcdwidets:6564","nightly:6543"]
```

6564 & 6543 are the largest values in their respective groups

> Code

```
var mainarray = ["abcdwidets:1234","abcdwidets:3432","abcdwidets:6564","nightly:3423","nightly:6543"]
var arr = [];
var needle;
var i = 0;
var flag = 0;
mainarray.forEach( (element) => {
arr = element.split(":");
arr = arr.map((val) => {
return val
});

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and get the highest number for each `key` (the string before the `:`). Then [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the Map's [entries iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) (by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) back to an array:

```js
const mainarray = ["abcdwidets:1234","abcdwidets:3432","abcdwidets:6564","nightly:3423","nightly:6543"];

const result = [...mainarray.reduce((r, s) => {
  const [k, v] = s.split(':');

  if(!r.has(k) || r.get(k) < v) r.set(k, v);

  return r;
}, new Map())]
.map(([k, v]) => `${k}:${v}`);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is magical, could you let us know the usage of "..." when performing reduce on the main array.

Comment: Spreading a Map into an array, calls the [Map's entries iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) to create the array. The returned array is in the format of `[[key, value], [key, value], etc...]`.

Comment: Can be a bit cleaner ``const result = [ ...mainarray.reduce((r, s) => (([k,v]) => ((r[k] || 0) < v) ? r.set(k,v) : r )(s.split(':')), new Map())].map(([k,v]) => `${k}:${v}`)`` So `Map.prototype.set` actually returns the altered `Map`, and you can inline the function to split each entry

Comment: @NeilLunn - thanks. I know that 1Map.set()` returns the instance of the Map, and I used to write reduce methods using that. However, I've discovered that it's less readable.

Answer (score 0):

U will need to split the mainArray into 2 arrays like this

```
arr1=['abcdwidets', 'nightly', ..., n];
arr2=[1628, 0378, 6144, ..., n];
```

Once u have splitted your main array into these 2 then you just do a bubble sort and turn these 2 into 1 again.